# Extending a Perl non-Moose respecting encapsulation

Tags: perl, oop

I have a legacy project and I would like to extend a couple of classes in it with a few attributes and methods. I have access to the source code and know that the class uses a blessed hashref. I can of course go ahead and extend that hashref adding the keys that I want and re-bless into my class. But obviously this breaks encapsulation and I would like to avoid it as much as I can.

Is there a way to extend a (non-Moose) Perl class with attributes, not just methods, in a way that does not break encapsulation of the orginal class? The option to use Moose to do this is not available. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, one best practice for writing objects based on hashrefs is to prefix all fields with the package name, e.g.

```
package Parent;
sub new {
  my ($class, $x, $y) = @_;
  bless { "Parent::x" => $x, "Parent::y" => $y } => $class;
}
sub x { shift()->{"Parent::x"} }
sub y { shift()->{"Parent::y"} }
```

In that case, the issue doesn't arise, as every class has its own attribute namespace. But who writes his classes that way?

There are two ways I can think of to circumvent any problems: Proxying the original object via Autoload, or using inside-out object patterns. The third solution is to use prefixed attributes in your class, and hope that the parent never ever uses these names.

#### Inside-Out Objects

An inside-out object uses the blessed reference as an ID, and stores the attributes in lexical variables inside your class:

```
package Child;
use Scalar::Util qw/refaddr/;
use parent 'Parent';

my %foo;

sub new {
  my ($class, $foo, @args) = @_;
  my $self = $class->SUPER::new(@args);
  $foo{refaddr $self} = $foo;
  return $self;
}

sub foo {
  my ($self) = @_;
  $foo{refaddr $self};
}
sub set_foo {
  my ($self, $val) = @_;
  $foo{refaddr $self} = $val;
}

sub DESTROY {
  my ($self) = @_;
  # remove entries for this object
  delete $foo{refaddr $self};
  $self->SUPER::DESTROY if $self->SUPER::can('DESTROY');
}
```

This is a slightly dated pattern, but it works extremely well for your use case.

#### Proxy objects

We can contain a parent instance in a field of our class (i.e. both has-a and is-a relationship). Whenever we encounter unknown methods, we delegate to that object:

```
package Child;
use Parent ();
our $SUPER = 'Parent';
use Carp;

sub new {
  my ($class, $foo, @args) = @_;
  bless {
    parent => $SUPER->new(@args),
    foo => $foo,
  } => $class;
}

sub foo {
  my ($self) = @_;
  $self->{foo};
}
sub set_foo {
  my ($self, $val) = @_;
  $self->{foo} = $val;
}

# manually establish pseudo-inheritance

# return true if our class inherits a given package
sub isa {
  my ($self, $class) = @_;
  return !!1 if $class eq __PACKAGE__;
  return +(ref $self ? $self->{parent} : $SUPER)->isa($class);
}

# return a coderef to that method, or false
sub can {
  my ($self, $meth) = @_;

  my %methods = (new => \&new, foo => \&foo, set_foo => \&set_foo, DESTROY => \&DESTROY);
  if (my $code = $methods{$meth}) {
    return $code;
  }

  # check parent
  my $code = ( ref $self ? $self->{parent} : $SUPER)->can($meth);
  return undef unless $code;
  return sub {
    my $self = shift;
    unshift @_, ref $self ? $self->{parent} : $self;
    goto &$code;
  };
}

# write explicit destroy to satisfy autoload
sub DESTROY {
    my ($self) = @_;
    $self->{parent}->DESTROY if ref $self and $SUPER->can('DESTROY');
}

sub AUTOLOAD {
  # fetch appropriate method coderef
  my $meth = our $AUTOLOAD;
  $meth =~ s/.*:://; # clean package name from name
  my $code = $_[0]->can($meth);
  $code or croak qq(Can't locate object method "$meth" via package "@{[__PACKAGE__]}");
  goto &$code;
}
```

The ugly part is to fake methods defined in superclasses in the `can` code: We have to wrap the actual method inside a anonymous sub that unpacks our object to call the method on the proxied object. The `goto`s make our extra levels invisible to the called code, which is neccessary when somebody uses `caller`.

Most of this boilerplate proxying code can be abstracted into another module (and probably is, somewhere on CPAN).

Comment: The inside-out object is perfect for my situation. Thanks for suggesting it.

Comment: Just for completeness (I am certain you left it out for brevity) , for others who might benefit from your suggestion, I might add that your inside-out suggestion requires a suitable DESTROY method so that the corresponding key is deleted from %foo when the object instance goes out of scope

Comment: @Ya.Perelman Thankyou for spotting that bug. I've never used these patterns in actual code, so there are probably some more problems lurking in my answer.